# Refering to Visual Studio solution's package directories javascript files from within BundleConfig.cs file's RegisterBundles method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, datatables, bundle, bundling-and-minification

My technical development environment:

Visual Studio Community 2015
ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.0

I installed jquery.datatables version 1.10.15 plugin , and it placed the javascript files in the packages directory belonging to my Visual Studio solution.

I used Nuget's "Install-Package jquery.datatables -Version 1.10.15 " , and the jquery DAtatables javascript files were placed in ...blahSolutionDirectoryblahblah...\packages\jquery.datatables.1.10.15\Content\Scripts\DataTables..blah blah numerous jquery Datatables javascript files blah blah......

Inside the 
...blahSolutionDirectoryblahblah......blahSolutionDirectoryblahblah...\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs file's

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

 ..........................
 ........................
```

Could someone please show me how to mention the package's jquery Datatables javascript files in the BundleConfig.cs file's RegisterBundles method?

Comment: My thoughts: packages directory is not the part of solution, so they will not be coped to output directory on "publish". UPD: Your need to set "copy to output directory" to this files/directory some way

Answer (score 3):

In `RegisterBundles` for scripts:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js",
            "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));
```

and for css:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"));
```

assuming `_Layout` the templates for `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

and at the bottom of the `_Layout` View:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

with this (or something similar) within your DataTable View:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    });
</script>
}
```

You can change the names of the bundles to something else if you wish (you may not be using Bootstrap, for example) but this is what's named out of the box.